# ubuntu boot failed - lenovo g510 - ubuntu 18.04.1 - uefi and legacy

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, efibootmgr

Lenovo G510

The hard disk had the following partitions:

- 1GB vfat32 FreeDos
- 360GB ntfs MS OS (Win 7)
- 660GB ntfs other files
- 1GB ntfs PBR_DRV

I tried to install ubuntu 18.04.1.

I changed the BIOS settings as followed:
I disabled Secure Boot option and I switched from legacy to UEFI. 
When the BIOS was on Legacy I couldn't see the live cd.

So I booted the live-cd and I clicked install.  I chose "something else" so I changed the partitions as followed:

- 1GB vfat32 FreeDos
- 500MB vfat-12/16/32 EFI
- 8GB SWAP
- 120GB /
- 238GB /home
- 660GB ntfs other files
- 1Gb ntfs PBR_DRV

When I rebooted  I get the following message

> ubuntu boot failed

I clicked OK and I get the following message

> Default boot device missing or boot failed. Insert recovery media and hit any key. Then select "boot manager" to choose a new boot device or to boot recovery media

I clicked OK and I get a black screen

I burned an rEFInd live cd and booted so I could have access to my partitions. I used rEFInd cd to install rEFInd. I installed it and  rebooted it and  take the same result.

> ubuntu boot failed

I used the 18.04.1 live cd to reinstall grub. I did and I failed.

It's the first time that I am so confused and I don't understand what else to do. I don't understand what I have done fault.

Additionally after each one boot the dvd driver stopped to read any live cds

Sorry about my english. I am not a native speaker.

---

update: After a lot research I found this:

> Weird: A bug exists in some Lenovo computers (and perhaps in some others, too) that causes the firmware's boot manager to refuse to boot any boot loader that doesn't have the name Windows Boot Manager or Red Hat Enterprise Linux. If you have such a system, you must pass one of those names (in quotes) rather than rEFInd to efibootmgr via its -L option. This bug was reported to Lenovo in mid-November 2012, and by late 2013, at least some Lenovos were mercifully free of this bug

In terminal I used efibootmgr and it returns these:

> - BootCurrent: 0001
> - Timeout: 0 seconds
> - BootOrder: 0000,2001,2002,2003-
> - Boot0000* ubuntu
> - Boot0001* EFI USB Device (TSSTcorpCDDVDW SE-208GB)
> - Boot2001* EFI USB Device
> - Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
> - Boot2003* EFI Network

How can I pass "windows boot manager" or "Red Hat Enterprise Linux" in theses entries above? As I understand I have to rename the entry ubuntu. Am I correct?